# Not Equal to Fetching wrong data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When I put **=** in join it working perfectly but when I put **!=** Fetching Wrong Data.

```
$this->db->from('invoice_periodicity ip', 'ip.Periodicity_Ids != tpd.Id');
```

it giver all test_periodicity_details data repeat that result which I needed.

Example: I need to fetch 43 and 8 from 43 8 10 11
but it gives result . 43 43 8 8 10 11

```
$this->db->select('*', FAlSE);
$this->db->where('t.Flag', '0');
$this->db->where('tpd.Test_Id', $id);
$this->db->from('test_periodicity_details tpd');
$this->db->join('test t', 'tpd.Test_Id=t.Test_Id');
$this->db->join('school_information si', 't.School_Id=si.School_Id', 'left');
$this->db->join('test_status ss', 'tpd.Status=ss.Test_Status_Id', 'left');
$this->db->join('login_details ld', 'ld.Login_Details_Id=t.Test_Created_By', 'left');
$this->db->join('invoice_periodicity ip', 'ip.Periodicity_Ids != tpd.Id');
//echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

when i echo Query-

```
SELECT * FROM `test_periodicity_details` `tpd` JOIN `test` `t` ON `tpd`.`Test_Id`=`t`.`Test_Id` LEFT JOIN `school_information` `si` ON `t`.`School_Id`=`si`.`School_Id` LEFT JOIN `test_status` `ss` ON `tpd`.`Status`=`ss`.`Test_Status_Id` LEFT JOIN `login_details` `ld` ON `ld`.`Login_Details_Id`=`t`.`Test_Created_By` JOIN `invoice_periodicity` `ip` ON `ip`.`Periodicity_Ids` != `tpd`.`Id` WHERE `t`.`Flag` = '0' AND `tpd`.`Test_Id` = '1'
```

Comment: Could you get the generate SQL query ? and the data in the table you join ([mcve])

Comment: `$this->db->from('invoice_periodicity ip', 'ip.Periodicity_Ids != tpd.Id');` actually what you want from this..

Comment: @HikmatSijapati Fetch  all Data form test_periodicity_details which not exist in invoice_periodicity table.

Comment: @Blag Edited Question Show Printed Query.

Comment: don't see your edit

Comment: @Blag now you can see.

Comment: try this `<>` instead of this `!=`

Comment: @VBMali same result

Comment: try `$this->db->distinct();` above select statement

Comment: i Shorted the Query but it gives me same result - __SELECT * FROM `test_periodicity_details` `tpd` JOIN `invoice_periodicity` `ip` ON `ip`.`Periodicity_Ids` != `tpd`.`Id` WHERE  `tpd`.`Test_Id` = '1'__ but __=__ is working fine.

Comment: @VBMali $this->db->distinct(); gives same result. i commented query above it gives me same result.

Comment: May be it returns double ids just because of join in the table. (The joined table may have 2 records associated with ```test_periodicity_details``` table. Please check.

Comment: try using $this->db->group_by()

Comment: @AbhishekSharma if i use $this->db->group_by(); it shows all data but not repeatable. this will not work for me.